# Initialization of Angular objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular 1.x app and I want to initialize some $scope variables:

```
$scope.listing = {};
$scope.listing.title = 'This is a test';
$scope.listing.description = 'blah';
```

I also want to initialize an empty object, as follows:

```
$scope.listing.payment_types._ids = {};
```

This fails:

> angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property '_ids' of undefined

Seems I must do this:

```
$scope.listing.payment_types = {};
$scope.listing.payment_types._ids = {};
```

It seems long-winded, is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest the literals:

```
$scope.listing.payment_types = { _ids: {} };
```

The advantage of the object literal  notation is, that you are able to quickly create objects with properties inside the curly braces.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Creating_objects)